# Нужно спарсить параграф текста в котором под некоторыми словами есть гиперссылки

Tags: html, парсер, xpath

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Привет! Подскажите кто в теме. В настоящий момент по селектору - //div[@class='topic-body _news']/div/p/text() выдается текст из параграфов но в него не входят слова под которыми есть гиперссылка (Севастополе) - оно и понятно слова эти находятся в других тегах. Вопрос как сделать что бы эти слова также попали в результат?

Answer (score 0):

"//div[@class='topic-body _news']/div/p/descendant-or-self::*/text()" так выглядит запрос который делает то что нужно - а именно если текст параграфа содержит тэг "a" он не пропускает его, как было в первом варианте запроса а также берет из него текст. Помогла конструкция: descendant-or-self::* # контекстный узел и все его потомки.